# If $\{x\}=\{z\}$, does that necessarily mean that $x=z$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> *Proposition.* If $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}=\{\{z\},\{z,t\}\}$ then $x=z$ and $y=t$.

My question is that if $\{x\}=\{z\}$ then, must $x=z$ be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. We *define* $\{x\}$ to be the unique set $z$ such that $y\in z$ if and only if $y=x$.

So if $\{x\}=\{z\}$ this means that $t\in\{x\}$ if and only if $t\in\{z\}$, which means $t=x$ if and only if $t=z$, which means that $x=z$.

Comment: You said that ''... which means $t$=$x$ if and only if $t$=$z$''. Why? Must it be?

Comment: Well, $t\in\{x\}$ is synonymous with $t=x$, and $t\in\{z\}$ is synonymous with $t=z$. So if $t\in\{x\}$ if and only if $t\in\{z\}$...

Answer (score 0):

Yes because $x \in \{x\}$ (by definition). Hence $x \in \{z\}$. But the only element in $\{z\}$ is $z$ by definition. Hence $x=z$.

Comment: @Kahler Yes, $x$ and $\{x\}$ are **different** things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because a set with only one element has indeed only one (thus: unique) element :-)